# subsetting within magrittr pipelines without affecting the overall object

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

Currently the way magrittr's pipes work there's no way to mix vector-level and table-level operations. For example `str_sub()` only takes a vector, while `mutate()` only takes a table.

If you want to use both in the same pipeline the only options are splitting up the pipeline or nesting, both of which kind of defeat the point of piping:

```
##Multiple short operations and assignments:

iris$Species %<>% str_sub(.,1,-3) 
iris %<>% mutate(., compliments=str_c("pretty"," ",Species))


##Multiple layers of nested functions

iris%>%mutate(., 
  compliments=str_c(
    "pretty",
    " ",
    str_sub(Species,1,-3)
  )
)
```

What I want is to do something like the below (non-working) example. The closest approximation I've found is lots of superfluous calls to `mutate`:

```
iris %>% 
str_sub(.$Species,1,-3) %>%   
mutate(., compliments=str_c("pretty"," ",Species))
```

Comment: None of the code you have shared works. I am not clear what you are trying to do.  Can you explain?

Comment: Species was left lowercase by accident. I fixed the typo and changed the example pipelines so the changes they make are more immediately noticeable. What I'm trying to do is the first example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that you miss out the first argument of functions in the pipe, so your first example should look like this:

```r
library(magrittr)
library(dplyr)

iris %<>% mutate(Species = str_sub(Species, 1, -3), 
                 compliments = str_c("pretty", " ", Species))

head(iris)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species compliments
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2    seto pretty seto
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2    seto pretty seto
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2    seto pretty seto
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2    seto pretty seto
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2    seto pretty seto
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4    seto pretty seto
```

*(Also, you forgot to capitalize `Species`!)*

Comment: Magrittr also lets you stick the dot in the first argument for those of us pedantic enough to always want to explicitly have the first argument defined instead of completely invisible. It's likely an unintended side effect of automagically recognizing the dot operator, but I've never run into a scenario where it didn't work.